# Cannot access site with python requests, even after coping headers and cookies from browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests, http-headers

I'm trying to access site allegro.pl with requests:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'allegro.pl',
    'dpr': '1',
    'viewport-width': '1920',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 OPR/76.0.4017.177',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://allegro.pl')
s.headers = headers
r = s.get('https://allegro.pl/oferta/world-of-warcraft-30-dni-pre-paid-klucz-wow-eu-9538042175')
```

My first request is to get needed cookies and above method was working even yesterday, but today I'm getting 403 errors both times.

I have checked how request looks in browser, copied headers from browser, tried to copy browser cookies but still nothing.
I think that there must be a problem with requests module, somehow this website can see that I'm using script

Any ideas how to fix my program?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server is using a captcha service to check that JavaScript is enabled and that no ad blockers are running.  You can look at the content of the 403 response and see that message.

```
import requests
res = requests.get('https://allegro.pl/')
res.content

# returns:
<html>
<head>
<title>allegro.pl</title>
<style>#cmsg{animation: A 1.5s;}@keyframes A{0%{opacity:0;}99%{opacity:0;}100%{opac
ity:1;}}</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0">
<p id="cmsg">Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker</p>
<script>var dd={'cid':'AHrlqAAAAAMADKhs3_VXRtQAVxTsrg==','hsh':'77DC0FFBAA0B77570F6B414F8E5BDB','t':'bv','s':29560,'host':'geo.captcha-delivery.com'}
</script>
<script src="https://ct.captcha-delivery.com/c.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can still scrape it using selenium, there are lots of guides on this.

Comment: Any chances to enable javascript in python module? Selenium would be too slow :(

Comment: btw, the same html appeared before, when my script was working, but after getting cookies with first request I was able to access website, so I'm not sure if javascript enabled is mandatory, any ideas how to check it?